# Azure Durable Function loses input on retry

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

When I retry unsuccessful operation using Powershell Durable Functions, it throws this exception:
[image]

**HTTP Trigger script:**

```
using namespace System.Net

param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

$Request
$FunctionName = $Request.Params.FunctionName

$body = $Request.Body
$InstanceId = Start-NewOrchestration -FunctionName $FunctionName -Input $body
```

**Orchestrator:**

```
param($Context)

$data = $Context.input
Invoke-ActivityFunction -FunctionName 'O365_Holds_Activity' -Input $data
```

**Activity Trigger:**

```
using namespace System.Net

param([System.Collections.Hashtable] $message)
    
    ...
```

And **function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "retry": {
        "strategy": "fixedDelay",
        "maxRetryCount": 3,
        "delayInterval": "00:00:5"
    }
}
```

First run has no problem with input, but the second one throws such exception. Btw, http request example:

```
HTTP POST: http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/O365_Orchestrator
Body:

    {
        "holdIds": [
            1
        ],
        "action": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Durable orchestrators, I would recommend using the [Durable-specific retry feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-error-handling?tabs=powershell#automatic-retry-on-failure) instead of the generic [retry policies preview feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=powershell#retry-policies-preview), for example:

```
$retryOptions = New-DurableRetryOptions `
                    -FirstRetryInterval (New-Timespan -Seconds 5) `
                    -MaxNumberOfAttempts 3

Invoke-DurableActivity -FunctionName $FunctionName -RetryOptions $retryOptions
```

The advantage of this approach is that the orchestration state gets persisted between retries, which eliminates the risk of the orchestrator invocation timing out because of retries, and make your orchestration more robust in general.